# Maintain Http session for get and get operation in Curl TCL

Tags: tcl

i have created http seesion, using the same http session, i would like to do some get and set operations. 
Note : What ever the operation, data is present in XML Format, giving xml file as input. And need to fetch the status.
Is it possible using TCL curl.

Comment: Could you possibly rephrase your question? It is really hard to understand exactly what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

Look at the "cookie jar" usage examples for curl: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-c--cookie-jar

You can parse the cookie headers yourself and then store them in TCL variables if you use the -b/--cookie syntax instead, but this seems like more work than necessary. I would only do this if you have to avoid using temporary files. It is generally much easier to exec curl from TCL if you use temporary files for all input and output rather than using open to create channels.